# GDAL version 3 and higher does not work with Mapinfo and Decimal Fields

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, mapinfo

I'm having a problem trying to convert a MapInfo file from MID/MIF format to TAB format.
This problem occurs from version GDAL 3.0.4 and higher. On version 2.1.2, everything works without problems.

I use the following command

> ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo file" "test.tab" "test.mif"

Error following

> ERROR 1: Cannot format 1234.1 as a 20.16 field
> ERROR 3: Failed writing attributes for feature id 1 in test.tab
> ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 1 from layer test.
> ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
> translation of layer test (use -skipfailures to skip errors)

Here example of MapInfo file MID/MIF format

[test.mif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk2me.png)

[test.mid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auZU8.png)

Can anyone explain what is the reason for this error?

Im trying to use GDAL version 3.5, but still getting this error.

If I change the column type to Float than everything works fine.

But I can't just change the format of the existing file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value "1234.1" is to big.

From the documentation:

*Decimal fields store single and double precision floating point values.
Width is the total number of characters allocated to the field, including the decimal point.
Precision controls the precision of the data and is the number of digits to the right of the decimal.*

Your decimal definition "Decimal (20,16)" leaves only 3 digits for the integer part. Try a lesser value, i.e: 999.4 or change the decimal format to Decimal (20,15)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).